# Copying files from a shared folder network using PHP

Tags: php, file, networking, copy

I encounter an error when copying files inside a directory from another computer in a shared network using PHP. Basically here is the code i am using, the recursive function created by  @authorAidan Lister  to copy whole directories. **It is working on my local machine if I use a local file directory**, but when I change it to a directory from another computer it gives me an error concerning permissions.

I am sure that I took care of the permissions concerning folder access because I have gone as far as to allow "Everyone" to be able to have full access to the folder for testing purposes , but it still doesn't work. I am lost and have exhasuted all options I can think of.

**PHP** is the name of my local machine.

**VMSTBOX** is the name of the computer with the files i am trying to access.

Also, when I use " chmod("\\VMSTBOX\Users", 0777); "in my PHP code.It also gives me a "permission denied " error. I think this is related to my issue.

I have posted a chunk of my source code below along with the error message below. Thanks for any help

```
function xcopy($source, $dest, $permissions = 0777)

{
    // Check for symlinks

 if (is_link($source)) {
        return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
    }

    // Simple copy for a file
    if (is_file($source)) {
        return copy($source, $dest);
    }

    // Make destination directory
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest, $permissions);
    }

    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        // Deep copy directories
        xcopy("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry", $permissions);
    }

    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;


$filelocation="\\\VMSTBOX\\Files";

$newfilelocation="\\\\PHP\\VarTemptoCopy";

$status = xcopy($filelocation, $newfilelocation);
```

*CODE ENDS HERE*

Here is the error message i keep getting.

"Warning: dir(\VMSTBOX\Files,\VMSTBOX\Files): Access is denied. (code: 5) in C:\xampp\htdocs...."

Comment: It looks like you're running this on Windows, so I wouldn't be too concerned about `chmod` not working, as Windows file systems don't have file modes in the same way as Linux. However, the fact that it responds with `Access is denied` rather than silently ignoring it does suggest it is permissions related.

Comment: Yes, My assumption is permissions related but I ran out of options since I made the folder permissions set to Everyone with "full control" access. I don't know why it still wont allow me to access it

Comment: Can you read a file on that path using `file_get_contents`? Or does that also give you an access is denied warning?

Comment: Hello again Eborbob, It seems it still doesnt work even with file get contents, really appreciate your help                                                       $file = file_get_contents('\\\VMSTBOX\\Files', true);                                        still got an access denied code on this piece of code but again no error on the local machine directory